How to create a Stacked Bottom Sheet in Flutter with a visual effect showing the layers behind it?
I'm trying to create a stacked bottom sheet in my Flutter app, and I want to get a visual effect where the first sheet is slightly visible, allowing the user to see that there is a bottom sheet below it.
Here are some things I would like to achieve:

I want to display multiple items within the first bottom sheet.
When the user presses a button in the first bottom sheet, a second bottom sheet should appear on top of it.

I have tried using showModalBottomSheet, but I'm struggling to achieve the stacked effect. Are there any code examples or libraries that could help me implement this feature effectively?
The UI I expected

maybe u can't. Though u can try 1 draggable bottom sheet & one animated container( control it with GestureDetector(onVerticalDragUpdate: ) to use it as another bottomSheet

@JBJason So, conceptually, I am still using one bottom sheet and several containers on top of it, designed to function like additional bottom sheets.
